# Events Not displaying On page load in live, it works perfect on local

Tags: jquery, angularjs, laravel, ui-calendar

I am working on `Laravel` + `Angular` project and I am using angular `ui-calendar`, I am also using `jQuery` context menu plugin to create dynamic menu for each events.

I am using `fullcalendar#2.7.3`, `angular-ui-calendar#1.0.2`, `jQuery-contextMenu#2.4.4` and `moment#2.18.1`.

**The problem**: when i load full calendar page on server, It does not display current month nor any events on current month, but as i change the view like day or week and return to month view then it is displaying events properly. Because of this the `next`/`prev` and `today` buttons are not working.

This Code is working fine on local, I have also tried to change timezone but it still i face the issue.

[Github Issue Link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar/issues/504)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this issue by updating fullcalendar to 3.4.0

Comment: I dont agree with the review comment. Sure, the answer is pretty short; but I think when the OP claims that upgrading to another version of a tool solved his problem, that is good enough for an answer. But in order to make this more helpful to other people, you might consider adding a [mcve] to your question - avoid any links to external sites!